# Can I add an image somewhere between my menu buttons in WordPress?

Tags: php, jquery, css, wordpress

I want the navigation on my website to look like this:

Button 1 | Button 2 | **image** | Button 3 | Button 4

How can I do this in WordPress? I'm currently using this code to call the navigation:

```
            <?php 
                $args = array(
                    'theme_location' => 'primary'
                );
            ?>
            <?php wp_nav_menu( $args ); ?>
```

But I want a big image in the middle of the 4 buttons this code generated...

Thanks! :)

Comment: If you generate a list (`ul`) with your code... just add another buttom (with no link) and insert an image in the middle buttom through css (`background-image`)

Comment: Yeah unless you fancy delving into walkers (which is not much fun) make use of the fact you can add custom classes to custom links in menus and do something with CSS like @AlvaroMenéndez says :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
$('image').after('.menu-item:eq(1)');
```

Comment: So I don't really know alot about PHP... Where do I put this code exactly?

Comment: This is jQuery, usually it's placed in your .js file. If you're not familiar with javascript, maybe the other option presented in the comments to your question is better suited for you